# How to check if index of list is null in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this snippet of thymeleaf and I'm trying to go iterate through a list of user types and check if the current user has any of those user types and select them as appropriate. However if there are five total user types but the user only has one user type, the list will keep trying iterate and basically throw a index out of range exception.

```
  <select id="userType" class="form-control" th:multiple="true">
      <option th:each="userType, iterStat : ${userTypes}"
         th:value="${userType.userTypeId}"
          th:text="${userType.type + iterStat.index}"
          th:selected="${user.userTypes[__${iterStat.index}__].userTypeId==userType.userTypeId}">
       </option>
      </select>
```

Comment: "Keep trying to iterate"? Perhaps you're just wanting `contains`?

Comment: Does contains work with java objects or just strings and ints?

Comment: @chrylis I got it working with contains. Thanks!